# CSS style not applied to HTML

Tags: html, css, styles

I am not sure why my styling is not being applied.

*HTML

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <meta name="keywords" content=""/>
    <meta name="author" content=""/>
    <link rel"stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" media="screen"/>
    <title>Kelektiv88</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <p>T</p>
        </div> <!-- End #header -->
        <div id="nav">
            <p>T</p>
        </div> <!-- End #nav -->
        <div id="content">
            <p>T</p>
        </div> <!-- End #content -->
        <div id="footer">
            <p>T</p>
        </div> <!-- End #footer -->

    </div> <!-- End #wrapper -->

</body>
</html>
```

*CSS

```
body {
    background-color:#000000;

}

#wrapper{

    background-color:#000000;
}

#header{
    height:150px;
    border-width:2px;
    background-color:#000000;
}

#nav{
    background-color:#000000;
}

#footer{
    background-color:#000000;
}
```

This is very basic stuff and im not sure why the styling is not being applied. Might be tired brain syndrome, but seems like this is normal and should apply correctly. Help?!

Answer (score 4):

You have:

```
rel"stylesheet"
```

try:

```
rel="stylesheet"
```

Also, I don't know if this is a copy/paste error, but youre missing the opening "<" to your doctype declaration, and make sure your url matches with the actual filename, and that they are in the same folder

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your HTML have two errors:

**Line 1:**

```
!DOCTYPE html>
```

Change to:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

**Line 8:** *(main cause of the problem)*

```
rel"stylesheet"
```

Change to:

```css
rel="stylesheet"
```

If these fixes don't work, try reviewing the `stylesheet` path.

Comment: Caio, thanks for that! Its the little things.

Comment: @user3594110, you're welcome... don't forget to choose the correct answer! :)